# Scoping emmet expansion to round braces in VSCode?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code, jsx, emmet

I have quick suggestions and emmet enabled for javascript babel files.
I'd like it so that when a quick suggestion is made e.g. when I type `V` in the context below for it to select `View` - not for emmet to expand it into a `jsx` tag e.g. `<View />`

```
import { View } from 'react-native'
```

I would, however, like emmet to keep doing so for jsx tags that are scoped to a set of round braces e.g.

```
return ( 
    View // expands to: <View />
)
```

You can currently do this in sublime text by using a package called Scope Selector which exposes meta values like: `meta.group.braces.round.js` given a selection. I can then use this value as a context for a keybinding.

When I inspect the scope in VSCode however, there doesn't seem to be anything specific that I could use in the `when` clause of emmet's `Expand Abbreviation` keybinding:

[image]

Can anyone shed some light on how I may go about doing this - if it's possible. Thanks.

Comment: After construct the first pair of `<View></View>` manually can you use `tab` to expand the tags inside the View block? The first pair doesn't work for me, but after it figures out it's inside a jsx syntax, the tab starts to work for the emmet for me.

Comment: I can expand just fine at any level. The issue is that I only want to expand within a set of parenthesis. Emmet thinks the entire document is JSX. So it expands any element I tab on. So if what I want is a variable (such as the import statements above), and I tab to select that from quick suggestions, what I get is emmet taking over and expanding the element into a tag.